# Refresh token for the provider in terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud

Working on IBM Cloud and deploying infrastructure using Terraform.

I am using "restapi" module for the API calls. Everything works fine in my POC.

But when I run this piece of code in the project which runs over 2 hours, it fails with `401: unauthorized request` error. This piece of code executes at about 90 mins of the execution. I have found out that the data this restapi POST request passes is correct, just the token is expired by the time it executes.

Is there a way I can make this provider depends on some other resource? So that once those resources are created then only this provider is initialized?

Below is the code for the restapi I am using:

```
data "ibm_iam_auth_token" "tokendata" { }

provider "restapi" {
  uri                  = "https:"
  write_returns_object = true
  headers = {
    Authorization = data.ibm_iam_auth_token.tokendata.iam_access_token
    Content-Type  = "application/json"
    if-Match      = "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is also `iam_refresh_token`, so you can maybe try with that: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_auth_token#iam_refresh_token

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the internal terraform `timeout` function:

```
data "ibm_iam_auth_token" "tokendata" {
  ...
  timeouts {
    create: "1h30m",
    update: "2h",
    delete: "20m"
  }
}
```

If you'd like to dig into the docs, you can look [here](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/resources/retries-and-customizable-timeouts#default-timeouts-and-deadline-exceeded-errors).

Comment: So does this mean it will create the "tokendata" after 90 mins? and will update it again in 2 hours?

Comment: I get the following error. Seems that "ibm_iam_auth_token" doesn't support timeouts
```╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 2, in data "ibm_iam_auth_token" "tokendata":
│    2:   timeouts {
│
│ Blocks of type "timeouts" are not expected here.
╵```